# Multiple imagePullSecrets in a Kubernetes Deployment for the same URL

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I use a self-hosted instance of GitLab to store my Docker images. As we've recently set up Project Access Tokens, we want to pull images on AKS using individual Secrets for each registry. It means that we have specific credentials for each image in "the same registry".

Problem is, Deployments have a global `imagePullSecrets` list that refers to multiple Secrets. And those Secrets, which essentially hold different credentials (one per GitLab Container Registry), share the same Docker Registry URL!

Put simply, here an example Deployment:

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: one
          image: 'gitlab.company.com/project-one:1.0.0'
        - name: two
          image: 'gitlab.company.com/project-two:1.2.0'
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: secret-project-one
        - name: secret-project-two
```

The Secret 1 (secret-project-one):

```json
{
  "auths": {
    "https://gitlab.company.com": {
      "username": "project_111_bot",
      "password": "password-project-one",
      "auth": "Password"
    }
  }
}
```

And the Secret 2 (secret-project-two):

```json
{
  "auths": {
    "https://gitlab.company.com": {
      "username": "project_222_bot",
      "password": "password-project-two",
      "auth": "Password"
    }
  }
}
```

How is Kubernetes supposed to differentiate which Secret to use? Does it assume you have different URLs and will match the right Secret based on the image name? Or will it just try every Secret until one works?

Documentations don't seem to cover this scenario. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In source code I have found that it just tries all one by one, and returns the first one that succeedes.

I am not going to explain the whole process of how I have found this, but here is some of explaination/proof:

When [PullImage](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/a55bd631728590045b51a4f65bba31aed1415571/pkg/kubelet/kuberuntime/kuberuntime_image.go#L31) function is called, it [grabs the docker registry credentials](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/a55bd631728590045b51a4f65bba31aed1415571/pkg/kubelet/kuberuntime/kuberuntime_image.go#L38) and [loops over them](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/a55bd631728590045b51a4f65bba31aed1415571/pkg/kubelet/kuberuntime/kuberuntime_image.go#L59-L76) trying one by one to get an image, and [returns the first one that it finds](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/a55bd631728590045b51a4f65bba31aed1415571/pkg/kubelet/kuberuntime/kuberuntime_image.go#L72) that [does not result in error](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/a55bd631728590045b51a4f65bba31aed1415571/pkg/kubelet/kuberuntime/kuberuntime_image.go#L71).

Comment: Thanks for looking up! I also wanted to search for the source code but don't really have time/knowledge to do that now. From what you saw, do you know if, after a successful login, it will "remember" the right Secret for a given image? Or will it do that every time and thus, risk bans for too many failures?

Comment: I don't see it remembering any secrets/tokens. But why would you get banned? if k8s fails to pull an image it will try again after 10s, then if failed again after 20s, 40s and so on, so its not like it will keep in a loop trying to force-pull the image and gitlab will eventually blacklist you for too many requests in a short time (I think so). PS. dont forget to leave a like if you find my answer helpful :D

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks again for this helpful info! I didn't know it would cooldown. But in that case, this "dumb" way of doing could be smart enough to avoid getting banned indeed. I needed to be sure as our Kubernetes server hosts dozens of Deployments and pulls several times a day. People in my situation should also evaluate the impact of having potentially large amount of authentication failures when relying on that. Could trigger other network security mechanisms that could recognize a pattern there. Anyway, you answered my question like a champ. ;)

Comment: Seems like the image pull secret should be a scalar attribute of the Container ...